# Office 365 excel - opening older excel files

Tags: office365

I am new to office 365 but have older saved excel workbooks that I want to open. How can I do this?

Comment: Later versions of Excel should be able to open workbooks from earlier versions by simply telling Excel to open them (either with File/Open or by double-clicking on the file). If you've tried this and it didn't work, we'd need to know what the error reported is.

Comment: You can just open the older excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Just open them.

Excel is generally VERY capable of full backwards compatibility.

So,just double click the files or in Excel go to File > Open.

If you have a different question we'll need more information from you.